# ISO standard for languages with double characters

Tags: character, iso, digraphs

In my language (albanian) "sh", "xh", "th", "dh", "ll" are one sound (letter) so I want to know is there any ISO standard that supports double character letters or if anyone has got any suggestion what should I do so that my app knows that when user writes "th" it is not "t" and "h" but letter "th"?

Comment: A letter combination is still a combinations of letters, even if it denotes one sound and even if it is treated as a unit in collation and sorting (and possibly editing). You need to describe the problem much more specifically: what do you wish to accomplish in which context?

Comment: Google term: "digraph".

Comment: [Unicode!](http://www.unicode.org/faq/ligature_digraph.html) ..and no, digraphs are represented as separate characters.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the easiest solution is to ignore it. What's the problem with that? Even spell checking will work as long as you consistently treat it as the pair "th".

For complex applications like Text to Speech, you can ignore it too. That's done with phonemes, not letters.